# how to remove the border of a collapsible div/li in materialize.css

Tags: css, materialize

I am trying to create a collapsible within a collection list item. But I don't want the greyish border of the collapsible divs to be visible in this collapsible.

the markup:

```
<li class="collection-item">
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
        <li>
           <div class="collapsible-header">First</div>
           <div class="collapsible-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </li>  
     </ul>
</li>
```

the css:

```
.collapsible-header, .collapsible-body, .collapsible, ul.collapsible>li 
{
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0rem !important;
  border-top: 0px!important;
  border-right: 0px!important;
  border-left: 0px!important;
  border-bottom: 0px!important;
  box-shadow: 0px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: create a live fiddle please

Comment: `border:none !important;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> use this css  `box-shadow: none!important;`

```css
.collapsible-header, .collapsible-body, .collapsible, ul.collapsible>li 
{
  margin: 0!important;;
  padding: 0!important;
  border: 0!important;
  box-shadow: none!important;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li class="collection-item">
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
        <li>
           <div class="collapsible-header">First</div>
           <div class="collapsible-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </li>  
     </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.collapsible {
  
  box-shadow: none;!important
}
.collapsible-header {
  border: none;!important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li class="collection-item">
          <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
            <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header">First</div>
              <div class="collapsible-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
            </li>


          </ul>
```